# Cookies aren't saving between routes in Svelte Kit

Tags: cookies, sveltekit

I am somewhat new to SvelteKit, and I am trying to save cookies (specifically a JWT Token) from route to another route on the server side (with `+page.server.ts` and `+layout.server.ts`)

This is currently what I have coded:

```js
// /account/sign-in/+page.server.ts

import { invalid, redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { Actions } from './$types';

// ... other imports ...

export const actions: Actions = {
  default: async ({ request, cookies }) => {
    // conditionals to check
    console.log("cookie before creation", cookies.get("auth")); // undefined
    cookies.set("auth", "abc", { path: "/", maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, httpOnly: true }); // Creates the cookie
    console.log("cookie after creation", cookies.get("auth")); // "abc"

    throw redirect(302, '/client/app'); // Redirect to /client/app
  })
}
```

```js
// /client/+layout.server.ts

import type { LayoutServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async ({ cookies }) => {
  const jwt = cookies.get('auth');
  console.log("layout token", jwt); // undefined -- I expected: "abc"
}
```

Comment: Would recommend checking the dev tools. Response headers should tell you whether `set-cookie` was included and there usually also are ways to inspect what cookies have been saved.

Comment: (For me, code similar to this works as expected.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above worked after commenting out some of my other code specifically the conditional statements, for example, I have prisma code to check the database and compare the encrypted passwords to the entered password, and I commented out that code and moved my cookie code with dummy input outside so that it would run. After checking every conditional statement to see what worked/didn't work my code ran as expected.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, can you be more specific?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it has now been updated. Please comment if you have more questions!